# How can I view a table with more than 20000 rows in drupal7

Tags: drupal

I want to view a table with more than 20,000 rows in drupal7.I have try Fedds module ,but it's too large to import. So I want konw how can I view a table with more than 20000 rows in drupal7.

Comment: Hi I think you could get a better response if you added more information or some type of errors/code you have tried to use. Otherwise this seems fairly broad. But I would say, in Views, try using ajax that gets a smaller amount, and then for each pagination append to end of table. Could even try using a timeout on the loop if your server isn't very good and needs more time.

Comment: thank you for your answer.my server is not very good.I want show mt data like a excel or a table with function of search . The first row of my data like this : NNU01g00001     Arabidopsis|tr|F4I270|F4I270_ARATH      47.000  100     50      3       204     301     1054    1152    9.10e-12        71.2.

Comment: which have one modules can do it ？